# Derivation with respect to a measure

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I thought about this recently:

We first learn the "usual" integration, than we are taught that this is a special case, you are just integrating with respect to a particular measure: the Lebesgue measure, and that you can actually integrate with respect to other measures.

So why don't we think about derivates the same way? You might differentiate with respect to a measure the following way: if $\mu$ is a measure that is non zero on any non empty invterval, $\partial_\mu f(x) := \lim_{y\to x} \frac{f(y)-f(x)}{\mu([x, x+y])}$, when this exists.

I think that given that definition I have proven an analog of the fundamental theorem of calculus:
if f is a "$\mu$-differentiable" function on $[a,b]$, and $\partial_\mu f$ is bounded on $[a,b]$, then $\int_{a}^{b} (\partial_\mu f) d\mu = f(b)-f(a)$, where the integral is understood as the usual Lebesgue integral with respect to $\mu$.

I have a few questions:

-Does this make any sense to you, or is it grossly wrong?

-Does any of this exist, does it have any utility, or is it a special case of something I am not aware of?

-Is the analog of the fundamental theorem wrong (which means I made a mistake) or could it be right? My proof is quite long but I could try to write it using Latex.

Thanks

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem

Comment: You actually proved a very particular case of the Radon-Nikodym theorem (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem). For a nontrivial application see for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation.

Comment: Take a look at these notes, particularly Theorem 6.6, Theorem 6.8, and Theorem 6.10: https://www.math.cuhk.edu.hk/course_builder/1617/math5012/Real%20Analysis_Chapter_6.2017.pdf